# No puedo conectar mysql a my projecto de Django

Tags: mysql, django

En mi archivo settings.py pongo lo siguiente:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

y al tratar de hacer mis `python manage.py migrations` me sale el siguiente error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

¿alguien sabe a que se debe?

django==1.11.7
Ubuntu=14.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Host, ya intentaste poner la IP de localHost: 127.0.0.1

Comment: Tenia un par de problemas y reinstalé todo y seguia igual. Luego volví a intentarle con ese IP y funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Para conectar una aplicación Django con MySQL primero debes instalar el paquete `mysqlclient`. Una vez hayas instalado dicho paquete debes añadir en setting.py el siguiente código:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'nombre_base_datos',
    'USER': 'usuario',
    'PASSWORD': 'contraseña',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
    },
}
```

}

Comprueba en tu base de datos si tienes algún usuario enlazado a esa base de datos o si root tiene contraseña.

Comment: Tengo instalado el paquete mysqlclient==1.3.12
aunque he usado mysql y django es la primera vez que los uso juntos. 

sospecho que es algun problema con las contraseñas pero no se muy bien donde checar los usuarios.

Comment: Porque no usas el paquete de XAMP? yo lo utilizo en la empresa y con phpmyadmin te facilita mucho la vida, no es lo mejor pero es una forma fácil de trabajar con mysql en modo local. La configuración que te paso es la que uso yo y funciona bien.

Comment: Uso el paquete de XAMPP los habia usado por separado pero no logro conectarlos. Entro en localhost/phpmyadmin y ahi cree la base de datos solo no consigo conectarlas

Answer (score 0):

verifica que tengas instaldo esta libreria con pip `mysqlclient==1.3.12` me pasaba algo similar cuando no podia conectarme a mi base de datos

```
pip install mysqlclient
```